# Kubernetes ServiceStatus and LoadBalancerStatus

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, load-balancing, amazon-eks, kubernetes-service

I want to check if my Kubernetes `service` is okay via API.

According to the [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubernetes-api/service-resources/service-v1/#ServiceStatus), there are `ServiceStatus` and `LoadBalancerStatus` objects available, but they are always empty in my case.

Questions:

- In which cases is this data populated?
- Are there any examples (with data) for reference? (so I can test my status-check logic)
- Which fields are useful to investigate possible service problems?

Example:

```
kubectl get my-service -o yaml | grep "status:" -A10
```

Result:

```
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

What I want to get via API (like GKE):
[image]

Comment: Can you share the code you are trying?

Comment: I query Kubernetes API or kubectl for a service. I just want to get a basic "OK" or "not okay" status for my service - is this information available via the API? I guess yes, since I can see Status information for example in GKE.

Answer (score 0):

Your services have type=ClusterIP, so in order to see the load balancer value you need to use type=LoadBalancer instead, this will most likely assign a Public IP address for you.

If you just need to read the Cluster IP you can query it like this:

`kubectl get svc -n <somenamespace> someservice -o json | jq .spec.clusterIP`

Comment: Thank you. I know how to read all the data. I do not know under which conditions a error code is set (and where) and how I can simulate this? 
I see in GKE a simple Status column "OK" - this is what I want - what is the logic behind this?

Comment: I'd say OK is anything but all pod replicas ready and running, anything else gets not ok, either Pending or Terminating or Completed, etc.

Comment: Yes, but even if all pods are ready the service could be not "okay", due to network issues, wrong configuration (ports, policies etc).

Comment: That's why it is recommended to have liveness and readiness probes at minimum, and kubectl won't figure those for you if you don't tell k8s to probe it.